# How can I tell if I'm on a login page?

Tags: functions, hooks, login, actions

There are functions for `is_home()`, `is_blog()` `is_single()` etc...

What's the best way to tell if I'm on a page that is requesting that I login? I guess that would just be the wp-login.php page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paste this function in your functions.php or a plugin file:

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
if(is_login_page()){
  //this is a login page
}else{
  //not the page you are looking for
}
```

Comment: i would suggest wrapping it in `!function_exists('is_login_page'){}` for forward compatibility, but yes this does exactly what i want. thank you.