# Redirect not logged in users if they are on a specific page

Tags: redirect

I've seen this question posted before but not exactly trying to achieve what I want.

Basically what I want is:
If user is not logged in AND is on -this page- OR -this page- OR -this page,
redirect him to -this page- (which is a custom registration page)

I'm tweaking this piece of code, but it's not working. I'll appreciate any type of guidance.

```
<?php
function redirect_non_logged_in(){
  // if user is not logged and is on this pages
  if( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page( array( 250, 253 ) ) { 
    //This redirects to the custom login page.
    wp_redirect(site_url('/user-registration'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_filter('get_header','redirect_non_logged_in');
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is fine, but `'get_header'` it's too late.

Use `template_redirect` instead:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

  if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;

  $restricted = array( 250, 253 ); // all your restricted pages

  if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( '/user-registration' ) ); 
    exit();
  }

});
```

Be sure to not include 'user-registration' page id in `$restricted` array or you'll experience an endless redirect...

Comment: Really appreciate it. This works.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but rather than replicating the question, I'd ask you here. I use this slightly alternated code based on your answer: `add_action( 'template_redirect', function() { if ( !is_page('login') || !is_user_logged_in() ) { wp_redirect( site_url( '/login', 301 ) ); exit(); }});`, however, I still receive the redirecting loop. Can you point out what is wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that login is **not** a page, so `is_page('login')` can't ever be true. To know if you are on login page is not strainforward in WordPress, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28099/35541) to know how to do. @FrederickAndersen

Answer (score -3):

Install page restrict https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/

In settings choose login form show no

insert link in restriction message: `<a href="https://your login page/">Login</a>` to view this page/post